# NDEFReader in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nfc, webnfc

I'm trying to use `NDEFReader()` for NFC scan/write in React.
This feature works from Chrome 81 (you can try it on your mobile in Chrome beta today on links below).

[GoogleChromeNfcSample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/?fbclid=IwAR3zdbmjBh1_ryX-2wrKcPvLCDkAdNf2BU-pi8vF01U1QCgCOdP81WUqouk), 
[WhatWebCanDoTodayNfc](https://whatwebcando.today/nfc.html)

To enable this feature, you need to go into `chrome://flags/` and enable **Experimental Web Platform features**.

The problem is that I can't make this work in React. I use create-react-app with TypeScript and console output:

Cannot find name 'NDEFReader'

I think that this causes a webpack check. I already tried change some settings in tsconfig.json but nothing worked. Does anyone know, how to enable experimental js/ts compilation, to enable this feature?

Comment: Found working solution in React --typescript: https://github.com/takefumi-yoshii/webnfc-media-memo Demo: https://webnfc-media-memo.netlify.com/text-reader

Answer (score 7):

Web NFC folks provide TypeScript definitions at https://github.com/w3c/web-nfc/blob/gh-pages/web-nfc.d.ts

```
// Type definitions for Web NFC
// Project: https://github.com/w3c/web-nfc
// Definitions by: Takefumi Yoshii <https://github.com/takefumi-yoshii>
// TypeScript Version: 3.9

// This type definitions referenced to WebIDL.
// https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/#actual-idl-index

interface Window {
  NDEFMessage: NDEFMessage
}
declare class NDEFMessage {
  constructor(messageInit: NDEFMessageInit)
  records: ReadonlyArray<NDEFRecord>
}
declare interface NDEFMessageInit {
  records: NDEFRecordInit[]
}

declare type NDEFRecordDataSource = string | BufferSource | NDEFMessageInit

interface Window {
  NDEFRecord: NDEFRecord
}
declare class NDEFRecord {
  constructor(recordInit: NDEFRecordInit)
  readonly recordType: string
  readonly mediaType?: string
  readonly id?: string
  readonly data?: DataView
  readonly encoding?: string
  readonly lang?: string
  toRecords?: () => NDEFRecord[]
}
declare interface NDEFRecordInit {
  recordType: string
  mediaType?: string
  id?: string
  encoding?: string
  lang?: string
  data?: NDEFRecordDataSource
}

declare type NDEFMessageSource = string | BufferSource | NDEFMessageInit

interface Window {
  NDEFReader: NDEFReader
}
declare class NDEFReader extends EventTarget {
  constructor()
  onreading: (this: this, event: NDEFReadingEvent) => any
  onreadingerror: (this: this, error: Event) => any
  scan: (options?: NDEFScanOptions) => Promise<void>
  write: (
    message: NDEFMessageSource,
    options?: NDEFWriteOptions
  ) => Promise<void>
}

interface Window {
  NDEFReadingEvent: NDEFReadingEvent
}
declare class NDEFReadingEvent extends Event {
  constructor(type: string, readingEventInitDict: NDEFReadingEventInit)
  serialNumber: string
  message: NDEFMessage
}
interface NDEFReadingEventInit extends EventInit {
  serialNumber?: string
  message: NDEFMessageInit
}

interface NDEFWriteOptions {
  overwrite?: boolean
  signal?: AbortSignal
}
interface NDEFScanOptions {
  signal: AbortSignal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about Webpack checks or your tsconfig, or "experimental JavaScript".

It's just that there are no types for `NDEFReader()` available, so TypeScript thinks you have a typo.

You can stub in a type for `NDEFReader` with a file like `extra-globals.d.ts` (the name doesn't matter so long as it's a `.d.ts`) in your source tree. This basically tells TypeScript that the global Window interface has one extra field, `NDEFReader`, whose type you don't really know:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    NDEFReader: any;
  }
}

export {};
```