# NDEFReader in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nfc

I'm trying to use `NDEFReader()` for NFC scan/write in Angular Version 9. I found the following solution ([NDEFReader in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596876/ndefreader-in-typescript)), so I created a `.d.ts` file in my source tree and added the global interface `NDEFReader` but it's not working.

The Console Output is:

Cannot find name 'NDEFReader'

Does anyone know, how to enable this feature for Angular?

Comment: What platform/web browser version are you using? As this currently has very limited support as it is still "experimental", mostly only supported in Chrome on Android when the right config changes are made to Chrome.

Comment: I'm using Chorme. I wrote some code in JavaScript to write an read NFC Tags and it worked out well. But when i try it in Angular (TS) NDEFReader() has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `web-nfc.d.ts` file in a directory ( i.e. `src/@types` )

(Reference to this web-nfc.d.ts file: https://github.com/w3c/web-nfc/blob/gh-pages/web-nfc.d.ts)

Then edit the main `tsconfig.json` and add the directory reference to the types roots:

```json
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"],
```