Can't catch error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: NDEFReader is not defined" in vue3 Web Application
I am developing a vue3 app in which i want to use the NFC Web Api for reading and writing NFC Chips.
I am using typescript, vue routing and pinia.
It works fine when the device for the app has a NFC Chip that's active, but i want to show my own error page when the NDEFReader is not available for whatever reason.
The exact error is this:
NDEF.ts:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: NDEFReader is not defined
    at NDEF.ts:45:18
(anonymous) @ NDEF.ts:45

NDEF.ts is my type Definition file and at line 45 there is
export default NDEFReader

The error occurs in the type Definitions file for NDEFReader, as soon as the file is imported in my Store like this:
import NDEFReader from "@/models/NDEF";

and the store is imported and called in my vue component like this:
const nfcStore = useNFCStore();

I have tried to do a dynamic import which i didn't get to work with this import.
I have tried to use the ErrorCaptured lifecycle hook which works for other errors in the Store but not this one.
I have tried the Global error handling from vue in the main.ts like this:
app.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
    console.error("Fehler gefunden")
}

I have tried to surround "const nfcStore = useNFCStore();" with trycatch.
I have tried not to load the component before i check for nfc, but even when surrounding the router-view in the App.vue with v-if like this:
<div v-if="nfc">
  <router-view/>
</div>

and "nfc" is false the error is thrown.
Nothing seems to get a hold of this error.
How can i get a hold of this error to reroute to a error page, so the page isn't blank when NDEF isn't there?

NFC's support is not that great unfortunately.
Also, be careful because the API is only available over HTTPS, this is maybe why you're having errors sometimes.
If you really want to go this way, you can always try this to solve your problem or any other code snippets foundable on the Internet with a try/catch or similar approach. The dynamic import/errorHandler/etc are not the way to go for such native Browser API.

Meanwhile, regarding the poor support, I might recommend maybe using some QR code scanning rather. Might produce a similar result and with better support overall.

It is running over https and i do check whether "NDEFReader" is in "window", the problem is that the error is thrown before it can even check whether NDEF is there.

@Philipp-1A but do you try it in a browser that supports the feature? There is a matter of enabling some flags too.

I explicitly want to catch the error thrown when the browser or device doesn't support the NFC Web Api. Like i mentioned in my initial post it works when running on a supported browser and device i just need a way to handle the error which occurs when it's not supported.

@Philipp-1A interesting that it crashes that fast. Maybe try to see if that behavior still happens in a vanilla JS file with nothing else? I doubt Vue has anything to do with this but I am also not sure why such an error would be that hard to catch.

It does work with JS because i can just drop the Type Definitions import because i don't need types for JS.

@Philipp-1A oh, so this is just a typing issue? For that, give a search on GitHub because you are probably not the only one asking that question. Otherwise, you could always ignore the TS error.

It does seem to be a typings issue but i can't ignore it that easily. I  have tried it with "ts-ignore" and "eslint-disable-line" at the import and at the export default in the typings file which is the location given in the error message.

You can disable a range of lines with ESlint. You can also give this one a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59046041/8816585

Also with "ts-noccheck" i doesn't work. I don't know why but it is so hard to get a hold of that particular error so you can handle or ignore it in any way.

Give a try to that one then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65305136/8816585

These are the exact typings i use in my type definitions file.
